# Determining Whether String is Valid Integer Objective C IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I am developing an apps for iPad. I am wondering that how can I find out whether a string is convertable to double or not. For example, both [myString floatValue] and numberFromString method of NSNumberFormatter recognize some string like "123rrrrr" as a valid number and returns its number part which is 123!

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a NSScanner for these purposes. It has methods to filter floats and doubles from strings.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

The `NSNumberFormatter` method `getObjectValue:forString:range:error` will do what you want. This will parse a number in a given range of a string - set this to the whole string - and return the range of the string it used - if this range doesn't extend to the end of the string there is garbage after the number.

Here is a simple wrapper for it:

```
- (BOOL) getNumberValue:(out NSNumber **)parsedNumber
              forString:(NSString *)inputString
                  error:(out NSError **)error
{
    NSNumberFormatter *parser = [NSNumberFormatter new];

    // remove whitespace so we can easily test if the whole string was parsed OK
    NSString *trimmed = [inputString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    NSUInteger trimmedLength = [trimmed length];
    NSRange all = NSMakeRange(0, trimmedLength);

    BOOL status = [parser getObjectValue:parsedNumber forString:trimmed range:&all error:error];

    if(status && all.length != trimmedLength)
    {   // getObjectValue succeeded but garbage after number (if garbage before number getObjectValue will fail)
        if (error != NULL)
        {   // make appropriate error
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSCocoaErrorDomain
                                         code:NSFormattingError
                                     userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The value “%@” is invalid.", inputString]
                                                                          forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey]];
        }
        status = NO;
    }

    return status;
}
```